# How to use jQuery plus plugins and dependent libraries with Webpack

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, webpack, mockjax

I am trying to understand how to port an existing set of code to Webpack. Here's my scenario:

I'm using jQuery with Bootstrap, KendoUI, Mockjax, some jQuery plugin-ish libraries (e.g. bootbox, jQuery BlockUI). Previously (using requireJS), I was able to specify these dependencies in an array in the 'require' of my main app js, and everything was tied together nicely. Like this:

```
require(['dep1','dep2','...'],function(Dep1,Dep2,...) {do stuff});
```

Using Webpack I've encountered a number of problems:

- When I turn on the 'chunking' feature, my mock endpoints no longer
  work
- In one case, Webpack is creating a '0.js' file and I have no idea
  why, nor how to prevent it from doing so.
- In various cases it appears there are two (?) copies of jQuery, such
  that handlers or references to Kendo widgets don't work anymore
- When I tried to convert some wrapper code from an AMD style (with a
  'require' array followed by a function with formal params), I got
  numerous errors, such as Bootstrap not finding jQuery or everything
  appearing to load except none of the jQuery event listeners were
  working.

I've read a bunch of articles, and tried things like:

- using the `webpack.ProvidePlugin` in my Webpack config
- putting an 'alias' to the unminified jQuery in the `resolve` object of my Webpack config
- using the `imports-loader?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window` approach in my `module: { loaders: {}}` Webpack config object
- using the `imports-loader` approach in my main js in the `require`

So far, nothing has worked completely. I've gotten close, only to find (for example) that suddenly a Kendo widget doesn't seem to exist under the jQuery selection it previously was working under.

### Summary:

I'd like to understand how to make a bulletproof setup so that one and only one instance of jQuery exists, and everything that has jQuery as a dependency/relationship uses that instance everywhere in my code. Further, I'd like to understand how such a thing can be accomplished while using the 'chunking' feature of Webpack. If I separate my Mockjax endpoints (for example) into a separate file, I want them to function for any AJAX call anywhere, be it via Kendo or jQuery. If I define a Kendo widget (say, a dropdown) somewhere, I want to be able to get a handle to it from anywhere using the `$('.some-kendo-widget').data('kendoDropDownList)` approach.

I'm happy to read more articles if someone has links; I've searched and searched, and just don't seem to have the right vocabulary to find what I need. Surely someone else has faced this though.

Comment: What is the question? (if it's more than one, can you post them separately, so they can be answered?)

Comment: Here's an article on avoiding duplicates in your builds: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/manually-tuning-webpack-builds-284923f47f44

Comment: Thanks, will check out that article. I'll try to distill the questions into single posts, it's just that it seems like solving the jquery problem will solve everything else, but perhaps I'm being to naive/optimistic.

Comment: Adding this from Twitter in case it's helpful to someone else:

webpack AMD-style require([], fn) calls must be async, so they split that code into its own bundle to load as-needed - this is the reason for the `0.js` file

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

For legacy libraries like jQuery UI which rely on a global jQuery we've had to use the `ProvidePlugin`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
}),
```

But I'm just sort of grasping at straws here, good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I did try that, but didn't solve all of my issues. If I use that approach, will that guarantee any use of $/jquery in any other code reference the global, without re-initializing jquery?